# Contact form Submit button not refreshing when pressed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a contact form on a website with some mandatory fields.

If you miss a field and are prompted to fill out all fields, when you go back and fill everything out and hit send, nothing happens.

You must refresh the whole page and start again.

Basically the SEND button once pressed, doesn't work again, unless you refresh the page. How can I fix this?

Below the HTML and Script code. Any help is highly appreciated.

```js
$('#form-send').click(function() {
$('#form-send').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

var name = $('#form-name').val();
var email = $('#form-email').val();
var telephone = $('#form-telephone').val();
var message = $('#form-msg').val();
var option = $('#form-select').val();
var error = 0;

if (name === '' || email === '' || message === '' || telephone === '') {
  error = 1;
  $('#details-error').fadeIn(200);
} else {
  $('#details-error').fadeOut(200);
}

if (!(/(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(email))) {
  $('#details-error').fadeIn(200);
  error = 1;
}

var dataString = '&option=' + option + '&name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&telephone=' + telephone + '&text=' + message;

if (error === 0) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mail.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
      $('#details-error').fadeOut(1000);
      $('#form-sent').fadeIn(1000);
    }
  });
  return false;
}

});

});
```

```html
<div class="form-input">
  <div class="form-title">NAME</div>
  <input id="form-name" required type="text"></input>
</div>

<div class="form-input">
  <div class="form-title">EMAIL</div>
  <input id="form-email" required type="text"></input>
</div>

<div class="form-input">
  <div class="form-title">TELEPHONE</div>
  <input id="form-telephone" required type="text"></input>
</div>

<div class="form-input">
  <div class="form-title">MESSAGE</div>
  <textarea id="form-msg" type="text"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-input">
  <div class="form-title">&nbsp;</div>
  <button id="form-send">SEND</button>
</div>

</div>
<!--end of form holder-->



<div id="details-error">Please complete all fields and include a valid email</div>
<div id="form-sent">Thank you for your enquiry - We will be in touch shortly!</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$("#form-send").prop('disabled', false);
```

after every

```
error = 1;
```

Comment: this is perfect! Worked a treat.

Comment: On a different note, would you know why when the form is received the telephone number displays straight after the name, all in one line without spaces, while every other field is on its own line?